# loading data into azure blob using spark stream in Azure Databricks

Tags: pyspark, spark-streaming, azure-blob-storage, databricks, azure-databricks

I am trying this code in Azure Databricks:

```
jsonSchema = StructType([ StructField("time", TimestampType(), True), StructField("action", StringType(), True) ])

// readstream from azure event hub
df = spark.readStream.format("eventhubs").options(**ehConf).schema(jsonSchema).load() 
 streamingCountsDF = (df.withWatermark("Time", "500 milliseconds").groupBy(
      df.body,
      window(df.enqueuedTime, "1 hour"))
    .count()
)

//writing stream to azure blob
 streamingCountsDF.writeStream.format("parquet").option("path", file_location).option("checkpointLocation", "/tmp/checkpoint").start() 

file_location is the azure blob url.
```

I am hitting an error in the last step:

> org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Append output mode not supported when there are streaming aggregations on streaming DataFrames/DataSets without watermark;;

How can we resolve this?

Comment: Could anybody answer this. What Iam trying to do is to stream event hub data into azure blob.

Answer (score 0):

> Depending upon the queries we use , we need to select appropriate
>   output mode. Choosing wrong one result in run time exception as below.

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Append output mode not supported when there are streaming aggregations on 
streaming DataFrames/DataSets without watermark;
```

**Reference:** You can read more about compatibility of different queries with different output modes [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#output-modes).

In structured streaming, output of the stream processing is a dataframe or table. The output modes of the query signify how this infinite output table is written to the sink, in our example to console.

There are three output modes:

**Append** - In this mode, the only records which arrive in the last trigger(batch) will be written to sink. This is supported for simple transformations like select, filter etc. As these transformations don’t change the rows which are calculated for earlier batches, appending the new rows work fine.

**Complete** - In this mode, every time complete resulting table will be written to sink. Typically used with aggregation queries. In case of aggregations, the output of the result will be keep on changing as and when the new data arrives.

**Update** - In this mode, the only records that are changed from last trigger will be written to sink.

Comment: So, here we need to use Update?